# Creating music tracks from samples in ableton live

Tags: ableton-live, samples, ableton

Hello everyone I just wanted to ask that is it possible for to remake a track from samples in ableton live?

Comment: Are you asking, "from samples, in Ableton Live" or "from samples [that come with] Ableton Live"?

Also, are you thinking about "remake" or "remix"?

Live comes in three differently-priced versions, of which the "Suite" version comes with lots of samples. The "Standard" comes with a limited set of samples, but you get a lot of high-quality freebies as a licensed user. Mostly, samples for Ableton are distributed in a packaged Ableton Project called a Pack.

For "re-making" tracks, you would probably need to emulate some synths, so a few plug-ins (playable instrument "effects") are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ableton has two powerful samplers built in, [Simpler](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-instrument-reference/#simpler) and [Sampler](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-instrument-reference/#sampler). I think some of the smaller versions of Ableton (like Live Lite) only contain Simpler. But they both can be used to create sample-based tracks. You can change pitch, speed, start/stop points, as well as modulate envelopes, filters, LFOs and other useful things. It's a great DAW for this sort of thing.